# how to read write a custom column in outlook with c#

Tags: c#, .net, outlook

I'd need to read / write a custom column that I created in Outlook, using C#. Does anybody know how?

I have tried to use EWS, but I could not get anywhere.

Edit:

```
ExtendedPropertyDefinition myExtDef= 
   new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(DefaultExtendedPropertySet.PublicStrings,
                                  "Engineer",
                                  MapiPropertyType.String);
PropertySet propertySet = 
             new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties, myExtDef);

foreach (Item item in findResults)
{ 
EmailMessage message = 
           EmailMessage.Bind(service, item.Id, new PropertySet(propertySet));}
```

The above doesnt help at all. ExtendedProperty count is still 0. Honestly, this was my best guess, but I'm neew to C# and EWS as well.

Comment: Did you tried _anything_ so far?

Comment: yes, please see above.